# XamlParseException datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I get a `XamlParseException` and I don't know how to solve it. I want to be able to control the input.

xaml

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Naam" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ContactNameTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingContactNameTemplate}"/>
```

dictionary

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactNameTemplate" >
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Name" Source="{Binding Name}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <c:Text Min="21" Max="130"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditingContactNameTemplate">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Name" Source="{Binding Name}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <c:Text Min="21" Max="130"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

edit

my error

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: A Binding can not be set in the Source property of type Binding. A binding can only be set in a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

    public class Text : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public Text()
    {
    }

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult result;
        string text;
        if (((string)value).Length < Min || ((string)value).Length > Max)
        {
            text = value.ToString();
            result = new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
        else
        {
            text = "";
            result = new ValidationResult(false, "De naam moet tss " + Min + " en " + Max);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have put a binding inside the `Source` property of another binding - the source should be the target object that should supply the value if the `DataContext` doesn't already contain the source that you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source(v=vs.110).aspx - the `Path` property specifies the path to the binding on the object pointed to by `DataContext` or `Source`. At a guess, I'd say you probably just want to remove the `Source` attribute from both of your bindings.

Comment: i removed it and i get this

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: The specified value System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder threw an exception.

Comment: Well that sounds like there is now an issue with your resources - can you show your validationTemplate resource and your textBoxInError resource - or it could be that the datacontext of your template isn't right - have you inspected the datacontext during runtime?